# Python IDE autocomplete missing some methods from AppDaemon plugin class

Tags: python, plugins, autocomplete, package

I'm trying to use autocomplete for the `Hass` class from the Python [AppDaemon](https://github.com/AppDaemon/appdaemon) package. Autocomplete is showing some of the inherited methods from the superclass such as `get_state()`, but some methods are missing, such as `log()` and `get_entity()`. This behavior is the same in VS Code and PyCharm Community.

[image: Autocomplete from superclass]

[image: Autocomplete method from superclasses superclass]

Here's the skeleton of a class I'm writing, which inherits from `hass.Hass`:

```
import hassapi as hass

class AutocompleteTest(hass.Hass):

    def initialize(self):
        self.get
```

Here's the class it inherits from ([GitHub link](https://github.com/AppDaemon/appdaemon/blob/dev/appdaemon/plugins/hass/hassapi.py)):

```
class Hass(adbase.ADBase, adapi.ADAPI):
```

The methods I want to autocomplete are in the superclass `adapi.ADAPI` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/AppDaemon/appdaemon/blob/dev/appdaemon/adapi.py)). Here are the method definitions from that class:

```
class ADAPI:
  # This method shows in autocomplete
  @utils.sync_wrapper
  async def get_state(
    self,
    entity_id: str = None,
    attribute: str = None,
    default: Any = None,
    copy: bool = True,
    **kwargs: Optional[Any],
  ) -> Any:

  # This method does not show in autocomplete
  def log(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):

  # This method does not show in autocomplete
  def get_entity(self, entity: str, **kwargs: Optional[Any]) -> Entity:
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on, and how to get autocomplete fully working?

My requirements file:

```
hassapi
iso8601
requests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hassapi` package on PyPI ([hass-api/hassapi](https://github.com/hass-api/hassapi)) and your requirements file is unaffiliated with AppDaemon.

At runtime, AppDaemon does [`sys.path.insert(0, plugin)`](https://github.com/AppDaemon/appdaemon/blob/dcfd4d1/appdaemon/plugin_management.py#L46-L51) for its own `hass` plugin ([AppDaemon/appdaemon/.../appdaemon/plugins/hass](https://github.com/AppDaemon/appdaemon/tree/dcfd4d1/appdaemon/plugins/hass)) containing the `hassapi` module.

To get autocomplete, install `appdaemon` package instead.

1. Either change your import statement to directly import AppDaemon's `hassapi` module:

```py
# import hassapi as hass
from appdaemon.plugins.hass import hassapi as hass
```

2. Or create a file `hassapi.py` in the same directory as autocomplete-test.py containing:

```py
from appdaemon.plugins.hass.hassapi import *
```